# Knockout.js Checkbox checked and click event

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

We're trying to implement a checkbox and list with the following functionality:

- Clicking the checkbox will either clear the array if there are items in there, or add a new item if not.
- Remove an item from the array when clicking the Remove button, once the last item is removed the checkbox automatically unchecks itself.

The problem I am having is that if you click to remove each array item, then click the checkbox to add a blank entry, I'm expecting the checkbox to be checked again (as per the checked observable), however it is not?

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/UBsW5/3/

```
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: PreviousSurnames().length > 0, click: $root.PreviousSurnames_Click" />Previous Surname(s)?
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: PreviousSurnames">
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data">
            <span data-bind="click: $root.removePreviousSurname">Remove</span>
        </div> 
    </div>


var myViewModelExample = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.PreviousSurnames = ko.observableArray(['SURNAME1', 'SURNAME2', 'SURNAME3']);

    self.removePreviousSurname = function (surname) {
        self.PreviousSurnames.remove(surname);
    };

    self.PreviousSurnames_Click = function () {
        if (self.PreviousSurnames().length === 0) {
            self.PreviousSurnames.push('');
        }
        else {
            self.PreviousSurnames.removeAll();
        }
        alet(2)
    }

}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModelExample());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a computed to monitor the length of the observable array. This way when the length reaches zero you can react to it automatically.

```
    self.surnames = ko.computed(function() {
        var checked = true;
        if (self.PreviousSurnames().length === 0) {
            self.PreviousSurnames.push('');
            checked = false;
        }            
        return checked;
    });
```

Now you will have the blank text box when all of the names are cleared. If you update your binding on the checkbox it will function properly as well.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: surnames, click: PreviousSurnames_Click" />Previous Surname(s)?
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/UBsW5/19/)**

Comment: What is the point of the computed? In your sample the code is duplicated in the computed and the `PreviousSurnames_Click` and you also needed to add the `return true;` in your latest edit to make the checkbox "work"?

Comment: The point of the computed is to react to when there are no items left in the array automatically. The code is duplicated because it's a fiddle. The refactoring of this example is an easy process. I updated it to remove the duplicate code, however. In your example the textbox doesn't appear when all of the items are cleared.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using together the `click` and the `checked` then you need to `return true` from your click handler to [allow the browser default click action](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_3_allowing_the_default_click_action) which is in this case checking the checkbox:

```
self.PreviousSurnames_Click = function () {
    if (self.PreviousSurnames().length === 0) {
        self.PreviousSurnames.push('');
    }
    else {
        self.PreviousSurnames.removeAll();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7W9dY/).